# Pushing packets captured from an interface to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, jnetpcap

```
import kafka.serializer.Encoder
import kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties
import org.jnetpcap.packet.PcapPacket
class PcapEncoder(verifiableProperties: VerifiableProperties) extends Encoder[PcapPacket]  { override def toBytes(customMessage: PcapPacket): Array[Byte] = customMessage.transferStateAndDataFrom(PcapPacket : Array[Byte]) }
```

`This is the encoder that I have written to encode packets captured using jnetpcap library to pass it to kafka consumer. But I have errors, is this the way to implement encoder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have Kafka already installed and running, you would establish a connection to Kafka to a particular topic using one of the producer interfaces (perhaps kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer).  Then when you get captured packet, you pass it to the API.  Kafka has not problems with raw bytes.  When you are done, you close the connection via that API.

Comment: Thank you. Is it enough to write a kafka producer that captures packets using jnetpcap library and kafka consumer that receives the packets? Also, I need to do this in Intellij Idea.

Comment: You should be able to do that in Intellij. The setup you describes sounds reasonable but I don't know your requirements to say more

Comment: This is the code that I have written for capturing packets. How to implement this as a kafka producer ? https://github.com/swe0523/PacketCapture-in-Spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/PacketCapture1.scala

Comment: At the start of main() code, you would create a kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer instance, selecting the options you want.

Comment: (more complete) At the start of main() code, you would create a kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer instance, selecting the options you want and it will connect to Kafka.  At the end of the main() you would close the Producer.  In nextPacket() you would call send on the producer, including the PcapPacket.

Comment: I have pushed the packets to kafka and kafka receiver is able to receive the packets as string only. How to convert the received string format into pcap format so as to utilise the functionalities of jnetpcap library in receiver ?